# Find sum of noninteger number of terms

Tags: summation, square-numbers

How do you add a nonintegral number of terms together? For instance:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2.5} 1+2i$$

All I can think of is:
$$(1+2*0) + (1+2*1) + (1+2*2) + (1+2*?)$$

<sub>I am a beginner in math, so be patient.</sub>

**Edit**:
I am trying to express $x^2$ in a different way, because the following works when $x$ is an integer:
$$x^2 = \sum_{i=0}^{x-1} 1+2i$$

Also, the expected output to this particular expression is $12.25$.

Comment: where do you see this notation from?

Comment: Maybe find a formula for $$\sum_{i=0}^x 1+2i$$ in terms of $x$, then plug in $2.5$?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I created it. I am trying to express $x^2$ in a different way.

Comment: @D.R. can you elaborate further?

Comment: The notation is very poor.  There are two interpretations that I can think of., the first is that one could come up with an expression for $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}a_n$ and call it $f(n)$ and then extend the function $f$ to allow any real input, or perhaps it should be taken to mean the sum over all integer values of $i$ between $0$ and $2.5$, which would make the sum the same as though the upper bound were simply $2$ instead of $2.5$.  The issue is that there are multiple unequal ways to extend or express $f$, making the first interpretation not well defined.

Comment: The formula for your sum in terms of $x$ is $x^2$, and you would plug in $2.5$ to get $6.25$, but I don't think this is what you are looking for is it?

Comment: @D.R. you are exactly correct. I would like $6.25$ as an output.

Comment: The point of my approach is to fit a *continuous* function to your *discrete* sum, which is where I get $f(x)=x^2$

Comment: My point is that not only is one valid extension of the sum $(n+1)^2$, another perfectly valid continuous extension of the sum is $(n+1)^2+\sin(\pi n)$.  These give different values for $n=2.5$.  How do you choose that the one is more valid than the other?

Comment: @D.R. how does your formula fit a continuous function to my discrete sum?

Comment: @clabe45 "*how does your formula fit a continuous function to my discrete sum?*"  Are you asking why the functions agree on integer values?  Are you asking how he arrived at that specific expression for the general total sum?  Both of those can be explained using elementary techniques, often involving proofs by induction.  Are you asking how we can insist that $x^2$ is the "correct" extension to the discrete sum?  We cannot.  I will reiterate my earlier point that there are *many* continuous functions which agree on all integer values but can disagree at noninteger values for the sum.

Answer (score 1):

The common interpretation of $$\sum_{i=0}^a f(i)$$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^a f(i)=f(0)+f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f\left(\lfloor{a-1}\rfloor\right)+f\left(\lfloor{a}\rfloor\right)
\end{align*}
with $\lfloor a\rfloor$ the *[floor-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)*, denoting the greatest integer less or equal to $a$.

> In the current case we have
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{2.5}(1+2i)}&=(1+2\cdot0)+(1+2\cdot 1)+(1+2\cdot 2)\\
> &=1+3+5\\
> &\color{blue}{\,=9}
> \end{align*}

A word of warning: The sigma-notation $\Sigma$ and the addition symbol $+$ share the same *precedence* level.

> We have to use brackets if the term $2i$ should be summed up with the Sigma symbol,
>   otherwise the following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^{2.5}1+2i=\left(\sum_{i=0}^2 1\right)+2i=3+2i
> \end{align*}
>   which   is   usually not intended.

*Hint:* The scope of the sigma operator $\Sigma$ is solely defined via *[arithmetic precedence rules](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-rules-2009-1.pdf)*. The scope is given by the expression that follows immediately the $\Sigma$ and is valid respecting the arithmetic precedence rules up to an operator with precedence level equal to '$+$' or up to the end if no such operator follows.

You might find Chapter 2: *Sums* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik useful. It provides a thorough introduction in the usage of sums.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way that you can add sums without flooring $2.5$? I tried to understand [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042704003851), unsuccessfully.

Comment: @clabe45: This paper contains just a proposal for a kind of non-standard summation. As far as I can see it is based (at least) upon a solid background of complex analysis. I also think, it addresses generalisations which don't cover your needs. I encourage you to read the referred chapter 2 to better see what we can do with summation (it's a lot! :-)). Then you will presumably be in a better situation to decide how to setup the framework for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to express $x^2$ in terms of a summation, you can do

$$\sum_{i=1}^{x} (2i-1) = \sum_{i=0}^{x-1} (1+2i) = x^2$$

(However, this has limited use, because in order to evaluate it at non-integer values of $x$, you need to expand the summation into $x^2$ and calculate it from there, which defeats the purpose of the summation for values such as $x=2.5$.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I added in the question, $x^2 = \sum_{i=0}^x 1+2i$, where $x$ is an integer.

Comment: Also, my goal is to write the square of a number using different notation, not the same as $x^2$.

Comment: @clabe45 Oh! I think I see what you're doing. Let me edit my answer. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thank you, so there is no way to produce a result from a noninteger value?

Comment: @clabe45 Correct.

Comment: I'm not convinced there's no more interesting way to modify the definition of summation to get the right answer. After all, we've already modified it to produce things like $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac 1 {2^i} = 1$

Comment: @ArtimisFowl Sure, but that's a constant, not a function. Summation is defined on the integers, so we can not have a summation function that acts the same way as $f(x) = x^2$ because summation isn't defined on the reals. We can expand the summation and acquire $x^2$, but if we plug in a non-integer for $x$, then we aren't really summing; rather, we're evaluating a continuation of the summation to the reals. That's fine and dandy, but as far as I know, the process of evaluation must and will be indistinguishable from just computing $x^2$ for $x \in \mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Z$.

Comment: What about Euler's summation: $\sum_{v=1}^{-1/2} 1/v = -2ln2$

Comment: @clabe45 Are you referring to the result that the limit of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$ is $\ln 2$? Euler summation doesn't involve real (or even rational) upper bounds to summations. The claim that $\sum_{k=1}^{-1/2}\frac{1}{k} = -2 \ln 2$ is not true (for one, the lower bound is greater than the upper bound, so nothing is summed).

Comment: @TiwaAina, check out [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042704003851). It mentions that summation there. The only reason I am asking on this site is that I don't understand much of the article.