# How to find summation with both upper and lower bound included?

Tags: calculus, summation

I was trying to find something on how to solve this summation $$ \sum_{i=1}^{log(n)} {\frac{i}{log(n)}} $$
I think it might be just $$ \frac{\frac{log(n)*(log(n) + 1)}{2}}{log(n)} $$ according to $$ \sum_{i}^{n} i = \frac{n*(n+1)}{2} $$ and the whole thing divided by log(n).
I am not sure if this is correct, please help

Comment: $\log n$ is not an integer.

Comment: A related post might be https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543847/find-sum-of-noninteger-number-of-terms

Comment: Also, this article might help https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2004.08.009

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor} {\frac{i}{\log(n)}} =\frac{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor(\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor + 1)}{2\log(n)}$$ would be correct, using the floor function, for the reason you give.

If $\log(n)$ were an integer, for example if you were taking logarithms base $10$ (or $2$) with $n$ a power of $10$ (or of $2$), then your expression would be correct and you would have $\frac{\log(n)+1}{2}$ in that case when $n>1$.

But most people at this site take $\log$ to be base $e$, so $\log(n)$ is never an integer for integer $n>1$, while if $n=1$ then $\log(n)=0$ and you have division by $0$

Comment: Most people on this site take $\ln$ to be base $e$. $\log$ is less universal.

Comment: " $\log(n)$ is never an integer for $n>1$." How about $n=e^k$ for positive integer $k$

Comment: @Golden_Ratio - I was assuming $n$ is supposed to be an integer.  $e$ is transcendental so $e^k$ is not an integer for positive integer $k$

Comment: @Henry Right, OP didn't specify n is an integer though, so might be better to include that in your  post for completeness

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I have inserted  an "integer" to meet your point