# Can You Take a Summation with a non-integer upper boundary?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I am trying to determine a formula for determining the probability of rolling any given number of $s$-sided dice. I have come to a result where I have $(T-n)/s$ as the upper limit of a summation. Thinking that summations required integer upper boundaries, I applied the floor function and now have a good approximation of the probability. However, I want to get an exact result, not just an approximation. Is there any way to compute a summation when the upper boundary, is a non-integer, say from $r=0$ to $r=\tfrac 16$? For example, could I evaluate the below summation for values of $n$ that are not multiples of $3$?

$$f(x)=\frac 15\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n/3}j!$$

**EDIT.**

I am also looking for how to solve this equation if possible. It seems like it should be doable with some integration, by taking the sum using steps smaller than one. Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: How would you define the sum? For example $\sum_{n=1}^4n=1+2+3+4$, what would it be for non-integer boundaries?

Comment: Please do a little more work to look up [other answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543847/find-sum-of-noninteger-number-of-terms) next time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find sum of noninteger number of terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543847/find-sum-of-noninteger-number-of-terms)

Comment: @PC1, I am wondering if the step can be broken down for smaller non-integer numbers. Your sum went from n=1 to 4, but if you took smaller increments (say, infinitely small) then could you not find a sum for n=1 to 4.5? Or from n=1 to pi?

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental difference between sequences and functions of a real variable. Assuming for simplicity real-valued sequences and functions, defining a sequence amounts to specifying a map $\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$, while a real valued function of course is a map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. Although any function on $\Bbb R$ can be restricted to arguments in $\Bbb N$ (so a function gives rise to a sequence), this operation loses most information, and the function cannot be reconstructed from the sequence. For instance the function $f:x\mapsto 7\sin \pi x$ when restricted to $\Bbb N$ gives the zero sequence, from which $f$ cannot be reconstructed.

A summation is defined from a sequence of terms (which are added), not from a function on $\Bbb R$. If two expressions $A,B$ containing variable $i$ give the same values for integral values of $i$, then one must have $\sum_{i=k}^l A=\sum_{i=k}^l B$ whatever the bounds $k,l$ are, since one is taking the sum of the same sequence in both cases (and over the same range). This essential property of summation excludes using the values of $A$ or $B$ for non-integer values of $i$ in any way; indeed many combinatorial expressions are devoid of meaning when values other than natural numbers are given to the variable(s) they contain; this does not prevent them from being used in summations over that variable (assuming the range contains no negative numbers). As a consequence, one can only define above summations when $k$ and $l$ are integers. At a pinch one might say that the summation is over values of $i$ in the set $\{\, k+n\mid n\in\Bbb N, k+n\leq l\,\}$ which (given integer $k$) which would give a meaning for non-integer $l$, but the meaning would just be that of the summation with $l$ replaced by its integer part $\lfloor l\rfloor$.

One might be tempted to write a general expression for the summation as a function of the upper bound $l$ viewed as a real variable (so giving a real function which by restriction gives the right sequence of summation values) and then substitute a non-integer value for $l$. However this expression is in general not unique (or alternatively might not exist for any reasonable notion of "expression"), and the value at non-integer values might very well depend on the choice. Therefore this is not done in the definition of summations; a summation is always a sum of some number of terms (possibly zero terms), and that number of terms is always in$~\Bbb N$. (And so in particular when $l<k$, the sum is always$~0$. This is unlike the convention for integrals over intervals in $\Bbb R$, where for an interval traversed in the wrong direction the convention one takes the opposite of the value of the interval traversed in the right direction.)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can try is to solve your sum for integers and then use the same formula for any real number. I am not sure this makes perfect sense in your situation but for example, if you're trying to compute $\sum_{i=0}^xi$, this is equal to $\frac{x(x+1)}2$. You can compute a value for any $x\in\mathbb R$ and it will provide some result. Maybe this is relevant for you.

If you want to do more challenging function like $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^xi!$ then I suggest you to first check using the Wolfram Language. We can compute
[`Sum[n!,{n,0,x}]`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5Bn%21%2C%7Bn%2C0%2Cx%7D%5D), which gives a certain continuous and holomorphic function that matches your sum for integers.